# Yii2 Grid view syntax to access data from related model

Tags: php, yii2

for example I can retrieve the data in the view with this command:

```
<?=$model->instructor->manager->location['location_title']?>
```

I have a relation defined in `Instructor model` like:

```
/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getUser()
{
    return $this->hasOne(User::className(), ['id' => 'user_id']);
}

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getManager()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Manager::className(), ['user_id' => 'manager_id']);
}
```

and in `Manager` Model relations are defined like this:

```
/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getLocation()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Location::className(), ['id' => 'location_id']);
}

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getUser()
{
    return $this->hasOne(User::className(), ['id' => 'user_id']);
}
```

Now How I can retrieve the same data in `grid-view` as also add filter for the same.

Thanks.

**update: Gridview Code**

```
echo GridView::widget(
    [
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,

        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

            //'id',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            //   'username',
            // 'auth_key',
            // 'password_hash',
            // 'password_reset_token',
            'email:email',

            // 'phone',

            //'user_role',
            ['attribute' => 'created_at', 'label' => 'Last Login', 'value' => function ($data) {
                return $data->getLast($data);
            },

                'contentOptions' => ['style' => 'width:100px']
            ],
            ['attribute' => 'created_at', 'label' => 'Create Date', 'contentOptions' => ['style' => 'width:100px'], 'value' => function ($data) {return date('M d, Y', $data->created_at);}

            ],
            // 'updated_at',

            ['attribute' => 'status', 'value' => function ($data) {
                return $data->getStatus($data);
            },

                'filter' => ['10' => 'Active', '0' => 'Deactive'],
                'contentOptions' => function ($data) {
                    $clr = $data->status == 10 ? 'green' : 'red';
                    return ['style' => 'width:80px;font-weight:bold;color:' . $clr];
                }

            ]
        ]
    ]
);
```

**Update-1**

```
public function actionInstructor()
{

    $cond = "user_role='instructor' ";
    $searchModel = new UserSearch();

    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams, $cond);

    return $this->render(
        'instructor', [
            'searchModel' => $searchModel,
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider
        ]
    );
}
```

**update-2**

```
public function getInstructor()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Instructor::className(), ['user_id' => 'id']);
}
```

Comment: add your gridview code here

Comment: Hi Omer I have updated most of the relevant code from gridview.

Comment: the `$dataProvider` is for the `Instructor` model? correct?

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Comment: and you want which field to use `manager->location` relation ? in the gridview i am talking

Comment: I want the `location_title` in the grid view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify relations either as a string of relation names concatenated with `.` like below. Make sure you have the relations defined in the respective models the below is for the `$dataProvider` from the `UserSearch` model and your `User` Model should have the relation `getInstructor()` defined

```
 [
      'intructor.manager.location.location_title'
 ]
```

or

```
[
    'label' => 'Manager Location',
    'value' => function($model){
        return $model->instructor->manager->location->location_title;
    }
]
```

if I have the `$dataProvider` for the `UserSearch` model below should be the gridview code.

```
<?=GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,

    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

        //'id',
        'first_name',
        'last_name',
        [
         'label'=>'Manager Location'
         'attribute'=>'manager_id'.
         'value'=>function($model){
          return $model->instructor->manager->location->location_title;
         }
        ]
        //   'username',
        // 'auth_key',
        // 'password_hash',
        // 'password_reset_token',
        'email:email',

        // 'phone',

        //'user_role',
        ['attribute' => 'created_at', 'label' => 'Last Login', 'value' => function ($data) {
            return $data->getLast($data);
        },

            'contentOptions' => ['style' => 'width:100px'],
        ],
        ['attribute' => 'created_at', 'label' => 'Create Date', 'contentOptions' => ['style' => 'width:100px'], 'value' => function ($data) {return date('M d, Y', $data->created_at);}],
        // 'updated_at',

        ['attribute' => 'status', 'value' => function ($data) {
            return $data->getStatus($data);
        },

            'filter' => ['10' => 'Active', '0' => 'Deactive'],
            'contentOptions' => function ($data) {
                $clr = $data->status == 10 ? 'green' : 'red';
                return ['style' => 'width:80px;font-weight:bold;color:' . $clr];
            },
        ],
```

Comment: Hi Omer - I am getting the error - `Trying to get property of non-object`. I just copied the relavant code - removing the typo that is replace dot by comma after `manager_id`

Comment: is the `$dataProvider` from the `InstructorSearch` model ?

Comment: that basically means that the relation does not have the specified foreign key in the `manager` or `location` model , but you need to check before that the `$dataProvider` is from the `InstructorSearch` model or not @Pawan

Comment: May be you are right. I coudn't find `InstructorSearchModel` file in the Model directory. but when I am able to retrieve the value in view with the code I have given in my question, should it not be possible to retrieve with the same info?

Comment: please add the controller action code in your post so that i can make sure what is happening @Pawan

Comment: Ok I will add that - but in view file there is a addtional query which might help - `$manager = User::find()->where(['id' => $instructor_profile->manager_id])->one();`

Comment: well, i cant see that query provided in the view code above and apart from that the Gridview is using the `$dataProvider` variable that is being passed from the `controller /action` so if you can add the code it would be easier to figure out @Pawan

Comment: @Pawan , :D dude thats the `UserSearch` model not the `InstructorSearch` wait it update the code , do you have a relation named `getInstructor()` in your `User` model

Comment: yes it is there. like - I am adding it to question.

Comment: @Omer - It is perfect. but it's filter is not working. do I need to add separate code for that?

Comment: well that would make it another question as you need to define the attribute inside the Search model for the User and update the `search()` method currently we are not using any model attribute for the column @Pawan

Comment: @Pawan just go ahead witht he changes and add a question if you get stuck somewhhere and tag me there

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will have a go at it and then add a separate question for that.